# Add new regressor into Prediction dataframe

Tags: python, time-series, facebook-prophet

In the `df_train` is column 'total' with amount and this is `regressor` for fitting.

How can I add `regressor` into future `dataframe`?

I need to take amount from `df_train` 12 months ago from `future['ds']`.

```
    model = prophet(interval_width=0.95,seasonality_mode='multiplicative',changepoint_prior_scale=0.05,seasonality_prior_scale=0.08,yearly_seasonality=True)   
    # Add the new future regressor
    model.add_regressor('total')
    model.fit(df_train)
    future=model.make_future_dataframe(periods=14, freq='MS')
    future['total'] = future['ds'].apply()????????????
    forecast = model.predict(future)
```

Help with code please.